# Is there a way to compare infinity which respects the part-whole relation?

Tags: soft-question, infinity, natural-numbers

There is the intuition that if one set is a proper subset of another, the former is smaller than the latter. For example, there are "more" numbers in the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ than in the set of even numbers = $\{0,2,4,\dots\}$.

The part-whole relation is a partial order. So the problem is how to extend it "naturally".

Can we give a criterion of ‘size’ based on this concept?

A first step may be the power set of the set of natural numbers. For example, we would like the set $\{the \ even \ numbers\}\cup\{1\}$ and the set $\{the \ even \ numbers\}\cup\{2\}$ be the same "size". A first try may be to assign each subset of natural numbers a "size" by its  natural density. However, this will make all finite subsets of natural numbers, and other subsets like the set of the primes the same "size".

Comment: It is said that Bolzano (1851)  tried to develop a theory of infinite sets that preserved the part-whole relation but was not successful.

Comment: We cannot even enumerate the subsets of $\mathbb N$. Nor is there a total order for infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ , neither for the sets nor for their "size". The infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ all have the same cardinality.

Comment: Do you really want a total order, so that no two different sets have the same size (e.g. finite sets with the same number of elements)?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$, the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$, is in bijection with $\mathbb R$, or any interval inside it, which have well-known total orders on it. So there is **a** (actually, there are frighteningly many) total orders on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$. Whether there is one which respects the inclusion order, I don't know, and I find it interesting. I second @Karl's comment though, any total order would associate different "sizes" to literally each subset, including those of same finite cardinality, which might not be what one wants.

Comment: How about refining the standard cardinality-comparison relation by including the subset relation? That is, define $A<B$ to mean $|A|<|B|$ or $A\subset B$. This is a partial order.